# Cannot get Angular Routing Working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to build a SPA using AngularJS.  However, I cannot get the routing working for the life of me.  Basically I cannot get it to where when you click on one of the list items it routes the view to display different content.

I'm thinking that maybe one of the angularJS files is cancelling itself out or that I am messing up something in the directive.
index.html:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(
  ["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider",
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");

      $stateProvider
        .state("home", {
          url: "/home",
          templateUrl: "assetView.html",
          controller: "MainController"
        })
        .state("assetView", {
          url: "/assetView",
          templateUrl: "assetView.html",
          controller: "MainController"
        })



      ;

    }
  ]);
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.controller('MainController', function MainController($scope){

console.log("inside of MainController");
var vm = this;
$scope.selectedAsset = undefined;
$scope.startDate;
$scope.endDate;
// Current array for testing typeahead feature
// This needs to be an ajax call in the future to populate
// the asset array w/ all ticker symbols
$scope.asset = ['AAAP', 'AABA', 'AABA', 'AAME', 'AAOI',
  'AAON', 'AAPL', 'AAWW', 'AAXJ', 'BMTC', 'BNCL',
  'BNDX', 'BNFT', 'BNSO', 'CAKE', 'CALA', 'CALD', 'CALI',
  'CALL', 'CALM', 'DWTR', 'DXGE', 'DXJS', 'ERII',
  'ESBK', 'ESCA'];

  /* Datepicker Functions */
  $( function() {
    var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
      from = $( "#from" )
        .datepicker({
          defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          numberOfMonths: 1
        })
        .on( "change", function() {
          to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
          startDate = getDate(this);
          console.log("start date: " + startDate);
        }),
      to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1
      })
      .on( "change", function() {
        from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
        endDate = getDate(this);
        console.log("end date: " + endDate);
      });

    function getDate( element ) {
      var date;
      try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
      } catch( error ) {
        date = null;
      }

      return date;
    }
  } );
/* End of Datepicker functions */


/* Chart Data */
    var myChart = Highcharts.chart('highchartsContainer', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stock Header Here'
        },
        colors: ['#4BA2EA', '#CBCBCB', '#266FAD'],
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Div', 'EL Fix', 'LTT']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Sample1',
            data: [1, 4, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'Sample2',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        },{
            name: 'Sample3',
            data: [2, 3, 4]
        }]
    });
/* End Chart Data */
/* Highchart 2 */
var myChart2 =
 Highcharts.chart('highchartsContainer2', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stock Header Here'
    },
    colors: ['#4BA2EA', '#CBCBCB', '#266FAD'],
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Div', 'EL Fix', 'LTT']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Sample1',
        data: [3, 1, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Sample2',
        data: [9, 8, 2]
    },{
        name: 'Sample3',
        data: [9, 2, 5]
    }]
});
/* End Highchart 2 */
/* Highchart 3 */
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=goog-c.json&callback=?', function (data) {
    Highcharts.stockChart('highchartsContainer3', {
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'GOOG Stock Price'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'GOOG Stock Price',
            data: data,
            marker: {
                enabled: true,
                radius: 3
            },
            shadow: true,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
});

/* End Highchart 3 */



});
```

```css
/* Body Styling */
body {
    background-image: url("images/background_image1.png");
}
/* End Body Styling */
/* help.html div */
#helpDiv{
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: red !important;

}
/* End help.html div */
/* Wrapper Styling */
.wrapper{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 30px 40px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 1350px;
}
/* End Wrapper Styling */
/* Header Styling */
.header{
    background-color: #66A8EA;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1250px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.leftTriangle{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-top: 46px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 25px 20px 0;
    border-color: transparent #054e9c transparent transparent;
}
.rightTriangle{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px 25px 0 0;
    border-color: #054e9c transparent transparent transparent;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: 1225px;
}
#stockImageSVG{
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}

#uncImageSVG{
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
}
#searchBar{
    margin-left: 760px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 388px;
    margin-right: 60px;
}
#searchBarButton{
    margin-top: -1px;
}
/* Typeahead Dropdown Styling */
.dropdown-menu .active > a,
.dropdown-menu .active > a:hover {
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #B9DDFA !important;
}
/* End Typeahead Dropdown Styling */
#dateRangeSelector{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 760px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
#from, #to{
    color: #5B5B5B;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    border-color: #D4D4D4;
    font-family: Arial;
}
#toLabel{
    margin-left: 26px;
}
/* End Header Styling */

/* Navbar Styling */
#custom-bootstrap-menu{
position: absolute;
margin-top: 140px;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-right: 30px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: rgba(230, 225, 225, 0.51);
    border-width: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    width: 93px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 1);
    background-color: rgba(247, 247, 247, 1);
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    background-color: rgba(169, 207, 242, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 1);
    background-color: rgba(219, 219, 219, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #dbdbdb;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #dbdbdb;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #dbdbdb;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #e6e1e1;
}
/* End Navbar Styling */
/* Data Table Styling */
#tableArea{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin-top: 190px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
#tableContainer{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 480px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#dataTable2{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
}
/* End Data Table Styling */
/* Chart Area Styling */
#chartArea{
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: #EBEBEB;
   border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   margin-left: -10px;
   margin-top: 190px;
   height: 500px;
   width: 621px;
}
#chartContainer{
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    height: 480px;
    width: 500px;
}
/* End Chart Area Styling */
/* customArea3 Styling */
#customArea3{
    display: inline-grid;
    height: 520px;
    width: 555px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
}
#customArea3Container{
    height: 480px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
/* End Custom Area 3 Styling */
/* customArea4 Styling */
#customArea4{
    display: inline-grid;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -10px;
    height: 520px;
    width: 561px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
}
#customArea4Container{
    height: 480px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
/* End Custom Area 4 Styling */
/* Highcharts Styling */
#highchartsContainer{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 480px;
    height: 350px;
}
#highchartsContainer2{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 480px;
    height: 350px;
}
#highchartsContainer3{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 480px;
    height: 350px;
}
/* End Highcharts Styling */
/* Print Button Styling */
#printButton{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 1150px;
}
#printButton:hover{
    background-color: #99badd;
    border-color: #fff !important;
}
/* End Print Button Styling */
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>c426</title>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />

  <!-- Angular JS / Angular JS UI Router CDN -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Style Sheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="project.css">
  <!-- Controllers -->
  <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/MainController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <!-- SweetAlert2 -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.10.1/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Highcharts CDN -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/5.0.14/adapters/standalone-framework.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
  <!-- Favicon for Browser Tab -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/uncIcon2.ico">

</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">
<div class="header">
    <img id="stockImageSVG" src="images/stock_bar_image.svg"/>
    <a href="http://www.unc.edu/" target="_blank">
        <img id="uncImageSVG" src="images/UNC_logo_white.png"/>
    </a>
    <div id="dateRangeSelector">
            <label for="from">From</label>
            <input type="text" id="from" name="from">
            <label id="toLabel" for="to">To</label>
            <input type="text" id="to" name="to">
     </div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div id="searchBar" class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for asset..."
      uib-typeahead="name for name in asset | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control"
      ng-model="selectedAsset"/>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button id="searchBarButton" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-search" type="button"></button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="leftTriangle"></div>
    <div class="rightTriangle"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">


    <div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a href="#">GOOGL</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="assetView">BIDU</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="home">YNDX</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">AAPL</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">IBM</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TWTR</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">VZ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">WIFI</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FB</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">IAC</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">GDDY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">AOL</a></li>
            </ul>
</div> <!-- Ends Custom Navbar -->
<button type="button" id="printButton" onclick="window.print();"
    class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-print"
    title="Print Page"></button>
    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <!-- THIS IS WHERE WE WILL INJECT OUR CONTENT ============================== -->
    <div class="container">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>

<div id="assetView">
    <div id="tableArea">
        <div id="tableContainer">
        <table id="dataTable2" class="table table-bordered">
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>{{asset[0]}}</th>
           <th>{{asset[11]}}</th>
           <th>{{asset[17]}}</th>
           <th>{{asset[20]}}</th>
           <th>{{asset[25]}}</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>a</td>
           <td>0.001</td>
           <td>0.002</td>
           <td>0.001</td>
           <td>0.002</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>b</td>
           <td>0.002</td>
           <td>0.003</td>
           <td>0.001</td>
           <td>0.002</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>c</td>
           <td>0.2</td>
           <td>0.3</td>
           <td>0.001</td>
           <td>0.002</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="chartArea">
        <div id="chartContainer">
            <div id="highchartsContainer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="customArea3">
        <div id="customArea3Container">
            <div id="highchartsContainer2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="customArea4">
        <div id="customArea4Container">
            <div id="highchartsContainer3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems that all routes are landing on `assetView.html`.

Comment: Remove everything you don't need to learn routng: jquery, bootstrap, ui-bootstrap, highcharts, etc. The configure soething that makes sense: not two routes using the same controller and the same view, especially when this controller is also used as the ng-controller of the body element. Using mixed versions of angular libraries is also a bad idea.

Comment: Yeah I did that just to see if the routing was working.  Basically if the routing is working then I would see the SPA go to assetView.html.  However, I do not see that

Comment: I think you  overwrite `myApp` in this line `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);`

Comment: I would start with what @AlonEitan said, you should only make the assignment once. then reference it everywhere else. Remove all `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);` except one, then you can put ui.bootstrap and ui.router in same

Comment: I have it working now.  Thank you Alon Eitan and alphapilgrim.  I just needed to get rid of the var statement that was creating the myApp variable twice.  I changed a few other things also.